# Send a weekly reminder email to all users?

Tags: email, massemailmessage

I'd like to send a reminder each Friday to all users of our Force.com system, to remind them to fill in their timesheets.

What's the best way to do this? Usually I do workflows, but in this case, there would be no trigger to set one of those off.

Answer (score 1):

Could you produce a report over the timesheet records and then schedule that to be e-mailed out to all users? That way you could also write it up to *not* pester people who have actually already done it (I'm sure somewhere in the world is a person who completes their timesheet in advance??).

Otherwise, I'd have to recommend looking at using [Scheduled Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) - which would allow you to write a simple Apex class and then set a weekly run job for it through the interface. Write your class, and then select the "Schedule Apex" button at the top of the Apex Classes page

[image: schedule button]

and pick your criteria for it to run:

[image: schedule page]

You could write a class that directly e-mails all your users. Luckily e-mailing your users won't consume your daily e-mail governor limit, as pointed out by sfdcfox below; from the docs:

> You can send an unlimited amount of email to your organization’s internal users, which includes portal users.

However, if you are more comfortable with using Workflow to send the actual mail (which might make it more maintainable/configurable than too much dependency on Apex code) you could use your scheduled Apex to instead "cause an effect" that would fire a Workflow and then leverage all of the power of the standard features there.

Comment: Emailing *users* doesn't count against the daily limit anymore...

Comment: of course, thank you very much @sfdcfox - I have amended my answer accordingly!